# I cannot find a way to choose this link using protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, protractor

I've used protractor to do a google search for me, but I cannot figure out how to get it to choose one of the search results. I can't figure out which locator I should be using.
This is the html code for the link I need to choose from the Google search.

`<a class="l" href="http://blogs.com/myblogs" data-ved="0ahUKEwirnPjLu4LMAhVJyT4KHVA7BUIQjBAIOTAB" onmousedown="return rwt(this,'','','','2','AFQjCNF30dtvyBUGNFpk4EstTTASxP...4w','0ahUKEwirnPjLu4LMAhVJyT4KHVA7BUIQjBAIOTAB','','',event)">About Us</a>`

This is the code that I have in my spec file to find click on the link.

`browser.driver.findElement(by.linkText('About Us')).click();`

That doesn't work for me and I'm not sure how else to be able to grab the link. It doesn't have anything like a model, or id, or name to be able to locate. Obviously I'm new to this, it's something I'm trying to learn on the side.

Comment: Could you post the complete code you have right now? And, if possible include the link to the target page. Thanks.

Comment: The preferred method is `element(locator)`, see http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder

Both of these should work: `element(by.linkText('About Us')).click();` or  `element(by.partialLinkText('About')).click();`

It would help to see more logging about what is actually happening rather than guessing at a solution.

Comment: @alecxe, this is my code here.  
    `describe('Protractor get to a page', function(){
 it('should navigate to a page', function(){
  browser.driver.get('http://www.google.com');
   expect(browser.driver.getTitle()).toEqual('Google');
 });
 
 it('should type in a search and navigate to a result', function(){
  browser.driver.findElement(by.name('q')).sendKeys('Onshore Outsourcing');
  element(browser.driver.by.linkText('About Us')).click();
 });
});`

Comment: @alecxe this is the link to the page i'm trying to get to [link](http://onshoreoutsourcing.com/about_us)
. I have to get there by going to Google and searching for "Onhsore Outsourcing" then I have to click the result that says "About Us".

Comment: @craig_n, the error I'm receiving is "Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefine. This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping." I posted my code I have so far in the comments above and as you can see I have tried using the code that should work, but it doesn't. I feel like it's something small I'm missing. I'm not sure what.

Comment: @alecxe, sorry the last line in my code I pasted should read `element(by.linkText('About Us')).click();` rather than with the browser.driver.by.linkText and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You should wait on the link presence first i think.

```
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[name="q"]')).sendKeys('Onshore Outsourcing');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.css('input[name="q"]')).sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER);
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.linkText('About Us'));
    });
    browser.driver.findElement(by.linkText('About Us')).click();
```